Is Page resource load bot and JSON take about 45% of the crawled requests in Crawl stats report normal from an SEO perspective?
In the Crawl Stats report, I noticed that 45% of the crawl requests are for JSON files and are initiated by the Page Resource Load bot in Google Search Console (GSC). Even though I have already blocked these files in the robots.txt file, they are still being crawled.
I am concerned that this might be an issue because a significant portion of my crawl budget is being used on JSON files instead of the main content (HTML). Can you tell me if this is a problem from a technical and SEO standpoint?
To clarify, all the URLs found are not present in the main HTML code but are instead related to APIs.
